# Accessing value in nested object

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I don't understand how I can access an value in a object that is an array with an object inside itself.

I've tried with the dot notation and [] and array.reduce. But I'm doing something wrong.

I've changed the values but the structure remains the same:

```
"test": {
  "title": "My title",
  "category": null,
  "info": [{
    "time": 10,
    "type": "minutes"
  }]
}
```

I need to get the values of time and type, but I get undefined.

Comment: Assuming that `test` is a property of an object `obj`, then you can simply use `obj['test']['info'][0][time']` and `obj['test']['info'][0]['type']`.  
Though, maybe you are fetchinf these data, so there might be synch problem. Where do you get this `test` object?

Comment: Thanks @MaheerAli, I forgot the `[0]` :)

Answer (score 0):

The final object is first element of array so you need to first access its first element.

```js
const obj = {
  "test": {
    "title": "My title",
    "category": null,
    "info": [{
      "time": 10,
      "type": "minutes"
    }]
  }
}
console.log(obj.test.info[0].time);
console.log(obj.test.info[0].type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dot notation to access the properties
Object `a` consists of the `test` object which in-turn contains the key `info` whose value is an array containing one object with the required keys

```
a->test->info->[{time,type}]
```

```js
var a = {
  "test": {
    "title": "My title",
    "category": null,
    "info": [{
      "time": 10,
      "type": "minutes"
    }]
  }
}

console.log(a.test.info[0].time)
console.log(a.test.info[0].type)
```